# Matlab determinant function has gone awry

Tags: matlab

The following is an excerpt from a program of mine:

`function [P] = abc(M,f);
if det(M) ~= 1, disp(['Matrix M should have determinant 1'])`

I allow the option for the user not to enter a value for 'f'.

When I run abc([2 1; 1 1]), the program works fine and it does what it's supposed to. But when I run abc([6 13; 5 11]) I am told "Matrix M should have determinant 1".

What on Earth is going on?

EDIT: In the command window, I entered the following:

`M = [6 13; 5 11];
if det(M) ~= 1, disp('Im broken');
end`

Matlab then told me itself that it's broken.

Thanks

Comment: To so boldly claim that *MATrix LABoratory*'s determinant function is broken for a 2x2 matrix...

Comment: `format long; det([6 13; 5 11])` gives you 1.000000000000007. If you take a class in Numerical Analysis you will discover that math on computers is a whole new world. I you are interested in the subject you can take a peek at [Cleve Moler's site](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/chapters.html) (inventor of Matlab)

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to the wonderfully wacky world of floating point arithmetic. MATLAB computes the determinant using an LU decomposition, i.e., linear algebra. It does so since determinant is wildly inefficient for arrays of even mild size unless it did.

A consequence of that LU decomposition, is the determinant is computed as a floating point number. This is not an issue, UNLESS you have entered a problem as trivially simple as you have - the determinant of a 2x2 matrix composed only of small integers. In that case, the determinant itself will also be a (reasonably) small integer. So you could resolve the issue by simply computing the determinant of the 2x2 matrix yourself, using the textbook formula.

D = A(1,1)*A(2,2) - A(1,2)*A(2,1);

This will be exactly correct for small integer matrices A, although even this may show some loss of precision for SOME matrices. For example, consider the simple, 2x2 matrix A:

```
>> A = [1e8 1;1 1e8];
```

We know that the determinant of this matrix is 1e16-1.

```
>> det(A)
ans =
                     1e+16
```

Of course, MATLAB displays this as 1e16. But in fact, the number generated by the det function in MATLAB is actually 9999999999999998, so 1e16-2. As bad, had I used the formula I gave above for the 2x2 determinant, it would have returned a result that is still incorrect, 10000000000000000. Both results were off by 1. You can learn more about these issues by looking at the help for eps.

My point is, there are some 2x2 matrices where computation of the determinant will simply be problematic, even though they are integer matrices.

Once your matrices become non-integer, then things really do become true floating point numbers, not integers. This means you simply MUST use comparisons with tolerances on them rather than a test for exact unity. This is a good rule anyway. Always use a tolerance when you make a test for equality, at least until you have learned enough to know when to disobey that rule!

So, you might choose a test like this:

```
if abs(det(A) - 1) < (10*eps(1))
  warning('The sky is falling! det has failed me.')
end
```

Note that I've used eps(1), since we are comparing things to 1. The fact that I multiplied eps by 10 allows a wee bit of slop in the computation of the determinant.

Finally, you should know that whatever test you are using the determinant for here, it is often a BBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAADDDDDDDD thing to do! Yes, maybe your teacher told you to do this, or you found something in a textbook. But the determinant is just a bad thing to use for numerical computations. There are almost always alternatives to the determinant. Again, this is called judgement, knowing when that which you are told to use is actually the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

You are running into the standard problems that occur due to the limitations of floating-point numbers.  The result of the `det` function is probably something like 1.000000001.

General rule-of-thumb: Never test floating-point values for equality.

Comment: What's the best way round it?

Comment: @MattLab: Define some tolerance level, and do e.g. `if abs(det(M) - 1) < thresh`.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an insight: `det` is not computed using the old formula you studied in linear algebra, but using more efficient algorithms.

For example, using [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) you can transform `M` in the equivalent upper triangular matrix and then compute the determinant as product of the main diagonal (being the lower triangle all zeros).

```
M = [6 13; 5 11]
G = M - [0 0; M(2,1)/M(1,1) * M(1,:)];
```

Theoretically `det(M)` is equal to `det(G)`, which is 6 * 1/6 = 1, but being `G` a **floating point** and not a **real** number matrix, `G(1,1)*G(2,2)~=1`!

In fact `G(1,1)` and `G(2,2)` are not exactly 1 and 1/6, but they have a very small relative error (see [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html), which on most machines is around 2.22e-16). Their real value will be around 6*(1+eps) and 1/6*(1+eps), thus their product will have a small error too.

I'm not sure if Matlab uses the Gaussian elimination or the similar [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).